# Form doesn't submit when called to

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I'm trying to submit a form on a new page that I open, via Chrome console.

It fills in the input field with "heeeey, wassup homie" but doesn't submit!
No errors are present.
(everything else works, and yes this is meant to be inefficient)

```
var startItem = 0;
var endItem = 59;
function postCom() {
    startItem++
    if (startItem <= endItem) {
        var win = window.open("http://avatar-nation.com/Store/Item.php?ID=" + startItem);
            console.log("opened window");
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (typeof win.document.forms[2] != "undefined") {
        } else {
            win.document.forms[1].elements[0].value='heeeey, wasup homie';
            setTimeout(function(){
                // Here is the problem!!!!
                win.document.forms[1].elements[1].submit();
            }, 1000)
            setTimeout(function(){win.close();}, 500)
        }
    console.log("Commented on item id " + startItem);
    }, 2000)
    } else { startItem = 1; }
}
setInterval(postCom, 5000);
```

Thank you to all help! Ask ANY question that you need.

Comment: you are closing the window at 500ms.... try to remove that and see

Comment: You're probably calling the method on the wrong element, you want to call it on the form. Change `win.document.forms[1].elements[1].submit();` to `win.document.forms[1].submit();`. Also make sure you don't have a control named "submit", as that will shadow the form's submit method. Also as Arun P Johny says, you are submitting after 1 second but closing the window after 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @RobG It submits now, but it acts like there is no input in the elements[0]